# can we inherit a class from one project to another in c# windows application

Tags: asp.net, inheritance

can we inherit frm a class in different project in c# windows application. I have a class in a project A the class in A has methods to print a doc apart from getting document to print etc.I need to separate the printing method from project A and put it in2 project b so that we can separate the gui part.Can any one tell me how to do that or provide an example if you have 1..              I create a new project under the same solution explorer but not sure what and how to do next

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a class library (dll) with the objects, and include it in both projects? That's common for anything you find yourself sharing among other [independant] projects.

```
MySolution
├ Project.PrintingLibrary
│ └ PrintingLibrary.cs
├ Project.ApplicationA
│ └ References
│   └ Project.PrintingLibrary.dll
├ Project.ApplicationB
│ └ References
│   └ Project.PrintingLibrary.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

In Project B, add a reference to Project A.
Create a new class in Project B, and specify that it inherits from the class in Project A as shown:

C#:

```
public class ClassB : ProjectA.ClassA    
{
//...
}
```

VB.Net:

```
Public Class ClassB
    Inherits ProjectA.ClassA
    '...
End Class
```